# Не получается обратиться к базе данных на сервере

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, vaadin, h2

Проект vaadin+h2+hibernate+tomcat пытаюсь обратиться к базе данных, но на этапе конфигурации выдает ошибку

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory (Class paramClass) { 
    return new Configuration() 
      .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") 
      .addAnnotatedClass(paramClass)
      .buildSessionFactory(); 
}
```

видимо, как-то связанано с неправильным jdbc:url

```
##URL for connection to DB 
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8080/~/public
```

#### Ошибки:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested 
service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] 
... 

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling 
DriverManager#getConnection 
...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8080/~/public
```

Проблема точно не в том, что бд PUBLIC нет, так как миграции через flyway работают корректно

Видимо, что-то не понимаю в самом фундаменте взаимодействия с бд, потому что как ни пытался гуглить решение не нашел

Comment: Вы пробовали перевести ошибку "No suitable driver found for"?

Comment: так драйвер есть
логи: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator 
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****, driver=org.h2.Driver}

Comment: хотя вот перед ней вот строка: 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator 
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8080/~/public]
И как получается подключить драйвер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скачайте [jdbc-драйвер](http://www.h2database.com/automated/h2-latest.jar), скопируйте его в каталог lib сервера Tomcat. Это должно решить проблему.